# Prevent users from accessing subdomain in Express

Tags: node.js, http, express, get

I am very new to web development and Node.js / Express. I have an Express server. In my client I send a GET request for some data in the DB. The GET request is handled by

`app.get( '/pathname', controller.getsomedata );`

The problem is, the user can now type in the URL domainname.com/pathname in the browser and get directed to that pathname. If they add in a certain queries domainname.com/pathname?query, they are able to retrieve data from the DB (this is supposed to happen), but I would prefer if GET requests to /pathname only occur from within the client code, not when the user enters it in the browser.

Is there a better way to do my GET request? Or is there a way to restrict users from accessing /pathname.

I apologize for the newbie question, but I don't know how to word it well enough to do a google search for the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to do that. If your client-side code is able to access something, malicious user can do that as well.

You can mitigate the issue by using custom HTTP header or something like that, but it's better to validate all data on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Allow whole client request as DB query may cause security issues. So be sure to validate query parameters and use them as DB query conditions.
If you want to query DB freely from HTTP query parameter, you should prepend authentication/authorization to the route.

```
app.get( '/pathname', function(req, res, next) {
    if (confirmThisRequestIsFromMe(req)) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.send(401);
    }
}, controller.getsomedata );
```